# Selenium webdriver send_keys() not working properly

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I am using selenium web driver to automate front end web UI actions in Python script. In this regard to input value to a text filed (mandatory field), `driver.find_element_by_xpath(<xpath>).send_keys(<value>)` code is used.

Though I am able to see that value has been typed in the concerned text field, an error message saying text box cannot be empty is being thrown on the UI.

Browser : 23.0 (Also tried with old version like 20.0, 16.0 which reproduces same issue)
Python Version : 2.7

Here is my code:

```
sel = webdriver.Firefox()
sel.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='minBid']")'.send_keys("2") 
sel.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Save']")
```

Upon running this snippet, UI complaints saying `min bid is not supplied`.

Please help solve this challenge. Thank you.

Comment: share the code with us...

Comment: How does the UI get the value from the field?

Comment: Here is the code snippet: ' sel = webdriver.Firefox() sel.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='minBid']")'.send_keys("2") sel.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Save']")'  Upon running this snippet, UI complaints sayin min bid is not supplied

Answer (score 2):

Try clicking on the field before input;

```
sel.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='minBid']")'.click
sel.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='minBid']")'.send_keys("2")
```