# Webdriver not saving entries

Tags: webdriver

I have a simple login page that I am testing using Webdriver. I have the user and password fields declared as webelements, which I look by id. Same with the sign-up button. I populate the user, and password fields before hitting sign-up, but things happen so fast, that it looks like sign up gets clicked before the user and p/w fields get populated, thereby always resulting in an error stating that the two fields cannot be empty. This does not always happen though. To be sure, I inserted a Thread.sleep after user and password setters, but didn't see any change. I can see that the fields get filled, and there is a wait time (which I introduced through sleep), but when the sign-up button is clicked, the user and password fields become red again as if they were not filled before hitting continue. I used Webdriver's fluent API to make sure the buttons are all available to be clicked, but that also didn't make a difference. Has anyone seen this behavior before? How did you solve it? (I haven't attached a code snippet here, since the scenario is really very basic).

Edit : Attaching the code snippet here :

```
@FindBy(id = "signUp_id")
WebElement signUpButton;
@FindBy(id = "UserName")
WebElement userNameElement;
@FindBy(id = "Password")
WebElement passwordElement;
writeInTextField(call(By.id("UserName")), userName);
writeInTextField(call(By.id("Password")), password);
Thread.sleep(10000);
call(By.id("signUp_id")).click();

    public WebElement call(final By locator) {
        WebElement webElement = fluentWait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(locator);
        }
    });
    return webElement;
}

 public void writeInTextField(WebElement we, String sText) {
    we.clear();
    we.sendKeys(sText);
}
```

I initialize fluentWait variable as :

```
    fluentWait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(waitTimeOutInSeconds,   
    TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollingEvery(pollingInterval,   
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class,  
    StaleElementReferenceException.class);
```

Comment: If it was a really basic scenario, then it would work.  Since it is not, you will need to provide more information before we can do anything other than guess.  The HTML & JS of the page, for example. And your code, of course.

Comment: Have edited my post to include the snippet.

Comment: The behavior is exactly similar to the one described in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484780/selenium-webdriver-send-keys-not-working-properly, except that I do it in Java. The suggestion there of clicking the element before writing values is not working.

Comment: @user3325862 is it throwing any exceptions, or just skipping over the fields?  If you debug and step through, can you see it click the fields?

Answer (score 1):

This is more of common,
f developers have used any js based actions to verify fields are filled properly.

You should try entering "tab" character after doing "sendKeys". And then it should work.

I am using [qaf](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf), which has listeners capabilities and I am doing 'clear" of webelement via listener whenever click happens which makes actual code look clean.